# Generating an interrupt from a user application in Windows

Tags: windows, x86, interrupt, isr

I have a question on interrupts for Windows x86 PC.

**Is it possible for a user program in Windows to generate an interrupt in the IDT and install a custom handler for that interrupt?**

I have some ARM experience in developing a preemptive scheduler for a custom RTOS on ARMv7 based system. This just uses a private timer with a custom IRQ handler in the vector table.

I want to be able to simulate this in a Windows PC environment but be as close to the original implementation as possible. Initially trying to do this without multi-threading because that would require changing a lot of the internals of scheduling functionality.

So in the ideal case I would really like to access the IDT to be able to be able to closely mimic the functionality of the ARM vector table. From my preliminary research this does not seem to be possible. But I just wanted to see if anyone else have any perspective on this that I may have missed.

P.S.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_descriptor_table#Hooking
Seems to suggest a method of "hooking" into the IDT from a device driver code. Has anyone had any experience with this?

Comment: When you say "user application", do you mean in the OS theory sense, i.e. in user mode = ring 3, asking the kernel to do stuff via a system call?  Or do you mean "3rd party" application that a user could install on a Windows system, which might include some kernel code that it installs as what Windows calls a "driver"?  In the latter case, hooking an IDT entry would be something you'd do in code that executed in ring 0 to start with.

Comment: I guess it would be the second one with us actually developing that 3rd party app. I am not that familiar with Intel but I would assume that all applications that you develop would be running in ring-3. So is developing it as a "driver" is the only way you can get out of ring 3 to ring 0 in order to modify or hook into the IDT?

On the subject of system calls, I was thinking that won't work since the thing that I want to ask the Windows OS to do (hook into the IDT) is not something that Windows OS allows.

Comment: Yes, exactly, I don't think Windows has any system calls that allow user-space (ring 3) code to register an address as an IRQ handler.  (Or most sane OSes, since IRQ handlers need to be mapped in the page tables even when a different user-space task is executing, so at best it would need a context-switch trampoline!)  Anyway yeah, if you'd said yes to the "user application" = "user-space process", the answer would have been a hard no. :P